# How to regex after equal sign

Tags: php, regex

I need to grab the text after the equal sign 
and... i suck using regex.

i managed to build this but it still grabs the string
including the equal sign

**this is what i got:**

```
(name).\s.(.*)
```

**Example String**
| name                    = New York City

I need to grab only the "new york city"
how do i get rid of the equal sign inside the regex

Any ideas?

Comment: `name = (.*)` maybe.

Comment: What you have tried? please put your code here.

Comment: @SumitBijvani i added the code i was managed to achieve... i really dont seem to understand regex i guess though i have been reading a lot these couple of days...

Comment: `name\s*?=\s*?([\S\s]+)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver - doesnt work. trying it on regex101.com

Comment: @vihan1086 that works! submit please ;) (you are fast)

Comment: Sure it does: https://www.debuggex.com/r/UVae42zhmSsQKOD0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this RegExp `name\s*=\s*([\S\s]+)`

> `name` checks for the text "name"
>
> `\s*` selects all whitespace (greedy) if there is any
>
> `=` Will match the *=* sign
>
> `([\S\s]+)` Will select all characters

Add the flag `i` to make it case-insensitive. If you wish for only one space to be valid, replace `\s*` with `\s{0,1}`

Add `[.]` instead of `[\S\s]` and the `g` flag to make it match multiple lines

[**RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/hY5lZ4/1)

[**Other Version**](https://regex101.com/r/hY5lZ4/3)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
name\s*=\s*(.*)
```

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fV3eT8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an expert but `^name.=.(.*)` worked for me.

Tested the regex at [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: it will match `names=something` also

Comment: just tried it again. for some reason it doesnt work for me - "Your pattern does not match the subject string."